# Blackberry application not signed Completely?

Tags: blackberry

Hi i am successfully signing my blackberry application until now but for the last 2 to 3 days i am unable to sign the application. Out of 212 signing keys 210 is succesfully signed only two are left and my pc hangs without signing the application please help.

Comment: I faced this issue once.. It happened to me due to providing wrong password..

Comment: but all the other applications are signing succesfully but i am having the problem in my current application only.

Comment: try creating a duplicate of that project and try to sign it.

Comment: did that too then too not responding

Answer (score 0):

I solved this installing a JDK downgrade to 1.6 and then updating it in the *C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\bin\bbwp.properties* file so it points to this specific java version:

`<java>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0</java>`